# Delete all files in child tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL tables:

```
create table dbo.Media ( 
  Id int identity not null
    constraint PK_Media_Id primary key clustered (Id),
  Created datetime not null,
)

create table dbo.MediaFile (
  MediaId int not null, 
  FileId int not null
)    

create table dbo.[File]
(
  Id int identity not null
    constraint PK_File_Id primary key clustered (Id),
  Content varbinary (max) filestream null
    constraint DF_File_Content default (0x)
) filestream_on [FILE]

alter table dbo.MediaFile
add constraint FK_MediaFile_MediaId foreign key (MediaId) references [Media](Id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
    constraint FK_MediaFile_FileId foreign key (FileId) references [File](Id) on delete cascade on update cascade;
```

I need to delete all Media rows with Created date older than 2 months and the correspondents MediaFile and File rows ... So I have:

```
DELETE 
FROM dbo.Media
WHERE Created < GETDATE() - 60
```

My problem is how to make sure all MediaFile and File records are deleted.

Comment: What is the ultimate parent table of your three tables?

Comment: Are the `DELETE CASCADE` referential constraints not working? I would expect that will make sure the related rows are deleted during the operation.

Comment: @DanGuzman Look closely, he is deleting from `Media`, not `MediaFile`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The parent table is Media. So I suppose the cascade when deleting Media will only delete MediaFile. Am I wrong?

Comment: Couldn't you turn around the reference from FILE to MediaFile with delete cascade? (i.E: give MediaFile the Id let File reference it) . Or can one FILE be referenced from many MediaFiles?

Comment: FWIW, instead of allowing my stupid mistakes to cascade, I've found it safer to write stored procedures to handle deleting hierarchies. There are various benefits: reality checks can be performed, a transaction can be included with its associated benefits, the base tables can be secured so that users cannot delete data directly, logging can be included, ... .

Comment: I'll answer myself, you have other Tables wich reference FILE, haven't you?

Comment: @Turo, yes I have

Answer (score 0):

```
delete [File] 
join MediaFile 
  on [File].Id = MediaFile.FileId 
join Media 
  on Media.ID = MediaFile.MediaId 
 and Media.Created < GETDATE() - 60

delete MediaFile 
join Media 
  on Media.ID = MediaFile.MediaId 
 and Media.Created < GETDATE() - 60
```